# How to enforce a layout for nodes containing other nodes

Tags: position, uml, plantuml

I use plantuml 1.2019.8 and graphviz 2.38

I want to position the `middle` node in the center of the diagramme and the `up` and `down` nodes above and below it.

But I cannot  move `up`, `down` and `middle` to the center while at the same enforcing that `right` shows on the right side and `left` on the left side.

```
@startuml

skinparam linetype ortho

node up
node down
node "\n\n<b>    middle\n\n" as middle
node " " as left {
 node "left" as in_left
}
node " " as right {
 node "right" as in_right 
}

middle -u- up
down -u- middle

right -u- up
down -u- right

left -u- up
down -u- left

@enduml
```

now this complex problem

```
@startuml

    skinparam linetype ortho

    node up
    node down

    node " " as left {
     node "left1" as in_left1
     node "left2" as in_left2
     node "left3" as in_left3
    }
    together " " as T {
     node " " as middle {
      node "middle1" as in_middle1
      node "middle2" as in_middle2
    }
     node " " as right {
      node "right1" as in_right1
      node "right2" as in_right2
    }
    }

    in_left1 .d. in_left2
    in_left2 .d. in_left3

    in_right1 .r. in_right2

    in_middle1 .d. in_middle2
    middle -u- up
    down -u-- middle

    right -u- up
    down -u--- right

    left -u- up
    down -u- left

    @enduml
```

Here is the [Result](https://liveuml.com/view/5d78de68804edc5ffc6afd7a)

but the `up` and `down` are again not centered with `middle1` and `middle2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `together` keyword to enforce that `middle` and `right` stick together. Left will then flow around it on the other side.

```
@startuml

skinparam linetype ortho

node up
node down
node " " as left {
    node "left" as in_left 
}

together {
    node "\n\n<b>    middle\n\n" as middle
    node " " as right {
        node "right" as in_right
    }
}

middle -u- up
down -u- middle

right -u- up
down -u- right

left -u- up
down -u- left


@enduml
```

Comment: thank you, i will test that, in fact, my diagramm ist bigger than this... but it may help. Are there any documentation about the layout strategy of plantuml?

Comment: Not that I know of. Personally, I only use the [PlantUML Reference Guide](http://plantuml.com/guide), which has a lot of examples for each diagramme type.

Comment: I extented the question with a more complex problem